# Deciding which node should have landscape

Tags: landscape, openstack-autopilot

When running the openstack-install a node is picked automatically from all those enlisted in MAAS to install landscape on. What are the pre-conditions for the auto-installer picking a node for landscape?

I'm currently using 7 physical nodes including 1 for MAAS and then another gets picked for landscape. The node that gets picked for landscape isn't always the best in my opinion as it could contain a lot of storage which would be wasted.

Is it possible to specify which node to use for landscape as part of the auto-installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix, after maas is deployed, only power on and commission the machine you want to be the landscape server.  Deploy landscape then commission the rest of the machines after you're in landscape.

I had to do this myself as it kept picking one of the more powerful machines from MAAS.  Landscape will deploy properly with only 1 machine listed in MAAS.

Comment: looks like this will be the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

@bc2946088 has a good answer, but there is official support for this in the openstack-install command, I believe.

```
JUJU_BOOTSTRAP_TO=openstack-vm-bootstrap.maas sudo -E openstack-install
```

Found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/installer/en/multi-install.html